# SUMIF Match Text Add Values

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet (in Google Sheets but would also like this to work in Excel if possible) that has a bunch of formulas using various ingredients. They are in the following format:

[image: Spreadsheet snippet]

How can I create a SUMIF formula that will scan this spreadsheet for a certain value, say "brown sugar" and add the value directly to the right?

I know how to do this on a particular column using the following formula:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A4,"*brown sugar*",B1:B4)
```

How can I do this for any column within the spreadsheet? Look for "brown sugar" and add the value to the right together with any other occurrences?

To take it a step further, how can I have a cell in the spreadsheet be my input field?

[image: ingredient]

Would like to be able to enter values using a wildcard and reference that cell (`A2` in the below example) in the `SUMIF`

```
=SUMIF(A4:A7,A2,B4:B7)
```

Thank you in advance for any help on this!

Comment: What do you mean by wildcards? Placeholders for other characters? In other words, what does `*brown* sugar` suppose to add up? All type of sugar, color being irrelevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following array formula:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(($A$1:$G$11=A15)*$B$1:$H$11,0))
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

To search text with wildcards use:

```
=SUM(IFERROR((SEARCH(A15,$A$1:$G$11))*$B$1:$H$11,0))
```

For Google sheets use:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(IFERROR(($A$1:$G$11=A15)*$B$1:$H$11,0)))

=ArrayFormula(SUM(IFERROR((SEARCH(A15,$A$1:$G$11))*$B$1:$H$11,0)))
```

Comment: This seems to work great in Excel but I'm getting an error in Google Sheets - "An array value could not be found." Also, how can we take this a step further to use wildcards within cell A15? Something to the effect of brown%sugar in case there is a value of "brown-sugar" or "brownsugar" within the spreadsheet. Thank you!

Comment: Works great! Any idea how I can implement the wildcard into the field as per the example above with brownsugar/brown-sugar?

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This worked perfectly for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

For both **Excel and Google Sheets** you can use

```
=SUMIF(A1:H11,A15,OFFSET(A1:H11,0,1))
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`SUMIF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583)
- [`OFFSET`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379)

Comment: Just curious. Have you tried this formula in Excel? Has it worked for you?